# Validate with Zend_Validate_Date on a time string

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-validate

Hey all I'm trying to validate a 'time' field using Zend Framework.

The docs seem to be pointing out that the following:

```
$tstarttime =  $form->createElement('text','t_start_time');
$tstarttime->setRequired(true)
    ->setLabel('Start Time')
    ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Date('H:i'));
```

I've tried this but no luck. Any ideas or alternative ways to validate a time in the format of HH:MM (H:i in php)

Thanks all!

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: this does not work! it doesn't validate the time if i provide 55:55

Comment: Did you set a timezone? `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 $tstarttime =  $form->createElement('text','t_start_time');
 $tstarttime->setRequired(true)
      ->setLabel('Start Time')
      ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Date(array("format" => 'H:i')));
```

Answer (score 1):

55:55 is not a valid time if it is supposed to be in hours:minutes and not minutes:seconds. there are only 24 hours in one day. apart from that, your example should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can validate with Regex (ZF2) .

```
public static function isValidTime($time){
    $validator = new \Zend\Validator\Regex ( '/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/' );
    return $validator->isValid ( $time );
}
```

Regexp Expression: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/